# Reverse characters of each words in vector string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, c++11, vector

```
vector <string> theWords;
theWords.reserve(100);

istream_iterator <string> stringReader(cin);
istream_iterator <string> stringReaderEOF;

while(stringReader != stringReaderEOF)
    theWords.push_back(* stringReader++);

display(theWords);
//reverse(theWords);
```

INPUT:

samin khan

OUTPUT:

samin

khan

After reversing:

nimas

nahk

How do I reverse the characters?

Comment: Reverse not reserve.

Answer (score 1):

This code will reverse all string elements of a `vector<string>`

```
#include <string> 
#include <algorithm>

void main()
{
    vector<string> a = { "abc", "pqr", "xyz" };
    for (auto& s : a)
    {
        reverse(begin(s), end(s));
    }
}
```

Comment: @SaminKhan it works. Add using namespace std. Also include vector.

Answer (score 0):

```
void reverse(string& s)
{
    int i = 0, j = s.length() - 1;
    while(i < j)
    {
        swap(s[i++], s[j--]);
    }
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

In main():

```
reverse(theWords[0]);
reverse(theWords[1]);
//.....
```